# Display different language in textview provided from web api

Tags: android, localization, textview

I want to have an android app where, i want to display text in some foreign language lets say urdu.. I will call a web service and will get urdu text. my question is can i set that text in textview as it is.

I have made an application in the past which can take the text from strings files for different localisation and can show the text however this is different use case, as i can not save the texts locally.

Comment: typically for such a case, you would tell the server what language you need. `my question is can i set that text in textview as it is.` -  by using `setText()` ?

Comment: @Droidman...thanks for replying.. for an example میں ہوں stands for "I am".. now if I want to  setText() on textview will this display?

Comment: yes, `TextView`'s can display Unicode characters